# Matlab Syntax Confusion

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have the following Matlab syntax and I don't understand what it is doing, particularly the xDiff == 2 part which looks like a weird way to reference a specific value in the tDiff array. Can anyone advise?

```
tTacho = tDiff(xDiff == 2);
```

tDiff and xDiff are 479999x1 arrays

Thanks

Comment: You need to read about logical indexing [here](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/search.html?q=Logical+Indexing&page=1). That line reads values from those locations of `tDiff` where `xDiff == 2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first operation `xDiff==2` returns a logical array which gives you the information, which positions in `xDiff` are equal to `2`. Then it applies this positions to the second array `yDiff`. Maybe this short example hepls (simplified):

```
xDiff   = [0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 2];    % simplified: only values 0 or 2
yDiff   = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];   
tTacho  = [    3 4         9];
tTacho2 = yDiff(xDiff==2);
```

In this example `tTacho` and `tTacho2` are the same. What we are basically doing: the 3rd, 4th and 9th position in `xDiff` are equal to `2`, so we take the values of the 3rd, 4th and 9th position of `yDiff` and store them in the new array `tTacho`. Be aware that the length of `tTacho` is dependent on how many values in `xDiff` equal to `2` (in this example case there are 3, hence we get a 3x1 array).

The arrays `xDiff` and `yDiff` seem to be related in some way, at least from a logical point of view they should be. I hope this helps!

Comment: Would you happen to know how to replicate this using python?

Comment: @StevenGoddard im not familiar with python, but what i can tell is that matlab has a very special language syntax, which, as the name indicates, focuses on matrices and on matrix operations. So in matlab you typically can replace loops with matrix operations.I think you wont be able to reproduce this code without using loops in python, but im not 100% sure.